# Difficulty placing a dynamic fill command within a "\path let ..." TikZ structure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted to create a sequence of images that show a rhombus being folded.  I'm able to do what I want, but the code is not very elegant.  I wind up (needlessly?) repeating chunks of code to get the effect that I want.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.35in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\tikzset{rhombus fill/.style={fill=blue!\number\numexpr30+#1\relax},
         my arrow/.style={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2.25]{stealth};}}}}
\def\mystep{6}
\edef\myangle{0}
\def\stepmyangle#1{\xdef\myangle{\number\numexpr\myangle+#1\relax}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}


%-@-(4)------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{currentstep}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/0,10/30,12/60,14/0,10/0,9/0}
  {\stepmyangle{\x}%%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate (W) at (0,2in);
      \coordinate (Y) at (0,-2in);
      \coordinate (X) at (1.14in,0);
      \coordinate (Z) at (-1.14in,0);

      \fill[rhombus fill=0] (W) -- (Z) -- (Y);

      \ifnum\x>0\relax
        \path let
                \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
                \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
                \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
                \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
              in
              coordinate (A) at ($(W)+(\n3-\myangle:\n2)$);
        \fill[rhombus fill=\y] (W) -- (A) -- (Y);
        \path let
                \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
                \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
                \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
                \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
              in
              coordinate (A) at ($(W)+(\n3-\myangle:\n2)$)
              %% Here results in an error message:  "Missing \endcsname insert"
              %%[fill,rhombus fill=\y] (W) -- (A) -- (Y)
              [draw,postaction={my arrow}] (A) arc (\n3-\myangle:\n1:\n2)
              ;
      \else
        \path let
                \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
                \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
                \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
                \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
              in
              coordinate (A) at ($(W)+(\n3:\n2)$)
              ;
      \fi
      %% Here doesn't work because it blocks the arrows.
      %%[fill,rhombus fill=\y] (W) -- (A) -- (Y)

      \draw[gray!20] (W) -- (X) -- (Y);

      \draw (W)
        \foreach \x in {A,Y,Z} { -- (\x) } -- cycle;
      \draw[dashed] (W) -- (Y);

    \ifnum\thecurrentstep>2\relax\draw[black,fill=black!20] (W) -- (A) -- (Y) -- cycle;\fi

    \end{tikzpicture}%%
    \ifnum\thecurrentstep=2\relax
      \vspace{2ex}\par
    \else
      \ifnum\thecurrentstep<5\relax
        \hspace*{\fill}%%
      \fi
    \fi
    \global\stepcounter{currentstep}%%
  } 

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

The **first** problem is that I'm repeating a block of code:

```
        \path let
                \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
                \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
                \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
                \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
              in ...;
```

It would be nice if I could set these values once and call on them later, from outside the path, when I need them.  I've tried something like

```
        \path let
                \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
                \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
                \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
                \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
              in \edef\myarclength{\n2};
```

But that resulted in an error.

The **second** problem is that I can't seem to just write

```
        \path let
                \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
                \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
                \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
                \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
              in
              coordinate (A) at ($(W)+(\n3-\myangle:\n2)$)
              [fill,rhombus fill=\y] (W) -- (A) -- (Y)
              [draw,postaction={my arrow}] (A) arc (\n3-\myangle:\n1:\n2)
              ;
```

and save myself repasting the code.  The last example results in an

```
Missing \endcsname insert
```

error message.

Comment: The first problem needs `\pgfextra{\edef…}` (or `\pgfextra \edef… \endpgfextra` or `[/utils/exec=\edef…]`). The second problem is that you just use `\y` which misses its argument `1` or `2`. And I think there will be a third problem: You can't fill some part of a path and draw another part. This will need to be done in two separate paths which means that you need either to save the `let … in` results in coordinates (if possible which it seems to be in your case) or to use `\xdef` in the first problem.

Comment: I've overloaded '\y'. Yikes. I should change the '\foreach' loop to iterate over '\xx/\yy' instead.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Could you write up the `\pgfextra` portion of your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second problem arises because you use `\y` as a `\foreach` variable as well as `calc`’s shorthand for the *y* values of `\p` coordinates.

Using `\foreach \xValue/\yValue in …`  solves this when you are using `rhombus fill=\yValue` then.

The first problem is a little bit more complex.
You can actually execute arbitrary TeX stuff on a path.
You can either use

```
\path \pgfextra{<TeX stuff>};
\path \pgfextra<TeX stuff>\endpgfextra;
```

or

```
\path [/utils/exec=<TeX stuff>];
%   or /utils/exec={<TeX stuff>} if <TeX stuff> contains , or =
```

But a macro defined with `\def`/`\edef` would only be defined on that path and won’t survive the `;`. You will need to use `\gdef`/`\xdef` here. (I don’t know where you want to use `\myarclength` so I can’t say whether there maybe another way to solve this.)

I see a third problem though:
You *cannot* `draw` part of a path and `fill` another part of a path (I dare you! The arc will also have a filling …).

In your case though you can save the coordinate `(A)` and draw the arc and use another part that `\fill`s the triangle with the saved coordinate `(A)`.

```
\path let
     \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
     \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
     \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
     \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
     \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
   in [draw, postaction=my arrow]
    ($(W)+(\n3-\myangle:\n2)$) coordinate (A) arc (\n3-\myangle:\n1:\n2);
\fill[rhombus fill=\yValue] (W) -- (A) -- (Y);
```

I realize this is not helpful because you first want to fill the area and then draw the arrow (where it would come in handy to save the `\n` values for later use).

Luckily, you *can* `draw` and `fill` parts of paths separately; actually, the `edge` path operator creates another path but we can use that:

```
\path let
      \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
      \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
      \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
      \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
      \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
    in 
      (W) edge [rhombus fill=\yValue,
                to path={--($(W)+(\n3-\myangle:\n2)$) coordinate (A)--(Y)}] ()
      (A) edge [draw, postaction=my arrow,
                to path={arc (\n3-\myangle:\n1:\n2)}]                       ();
```

Yes, we simply ignore `\tikztotarget` and directly specify our path in `to path`.

If you would take a look at the new loop header:

```
\foreach \xValue/\yValue[
  evaluate={\myangle=\myangle+\xValue},
  remember=\myangle as \myangle (initially 0),
  count=\currentstep from 0] in {0/0, 10/30, 12/60, 14/0, 10/0, 9/0}{
```

I have included your counters and auxiliary macros into `\foreach` options.

Furthermore, you maybe could try your diagram with one `\matrix` (so only one TikZ picture) but I guess this doesn’t belong to this question anymore.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.35in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations}
\tikzset{
  rhombus fill/.style={fill=blue!\number\numexpr30+#1\relax},
  my arrow/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2.25]{stealth};}}}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \xValue/\yValue[
  evaluate={\myangle=\myangle+\xValue},
  remember=\myangle as \myangle (initially 0),
  count=\currentstep from 0] in {0/0, 10/30, 12/60, 14/0, 10/0, 9/0}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate (W) at (0,2in);
      \coordinate (Y) at (0,-2in);
      \coordinate (X) at (1.14in,0);
      \coordinate (Z) at (-1.14in,0);

      \fill[rhombus fill=0] (W) -- (Z) -- (Y);

      \ifnum\xValue>0\relax
        \path let
                \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
                \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
                \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
                \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
              in 
              (W) edge [rhombus fill=\yValue,
                        to path={-- ($(W)+(\n3-\myangle:\n2)$) coordinate (A) -- (Y)}] ()
              (A) edge [draw, postaction=my arrow,
                        to path={arc (\n3-\myangle:\n1:\n2)}]                          ();
      \else
        \path let
                \p1=($(Y)-(X)$),
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
                \n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)},
                \p2=($(Y)-(Z)$),
                \n3={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
              in coordinate (A) at ($(W)+(\n3:\n2)$);
      \fi

      \draw[gray!20] (W) -- (X) -- (Y);
      \draw (W) \foreach \x in {A,Y,Z} { -- (\x) } -- cycle;
      \draw[dashed] (W) -- (Y);

    \ifnum\currentstep>2\relax\draw[black,fill=black!20] (W) -- (A) -- (Y) -- cycle;\fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \ifnum\currentstep=2\relax
      \vspace{2ex}\par
    \else
      \ifnum\currentstep<5\relax
        \hspace*{\fill}%%
      \fi
    \fi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I particularly like the part where you show how to include the counters in the `\foreach` options.